# How to make tkinter simpledialog.askstring not continue when cancel is pressed?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, simpledialog
from tkinter.messagebox import askokcancel, showinfo, WARNING

app = []


def main():
    USER_INP = simpledialog.askstring(title="App Name",
                                      prompt="Insert the name of the app:")

    print(USER_INP)
    answer = askokcancel(
        title='DELETION',
        message='Are you sure?',
        icon=WARNING)

    if answer:
        print(answer)
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "User pressed yes")
        app.append(USER_INP)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "User pressed cancel")


root = Tk()

myButton = Button(root, text='input', command=main)
myButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What I want to happen here is if the user presses the `input` button, then the `Insert the app name` window pops up. If he presses cancel I want it to just stop there and do nothing. To be more exact I dont want it to go into the `answer = askokcancel` part.

Comment: What do you get on `USER_INP` when you press `Cancel`? It is not hard to check the returned value of `USER_INP` to determine whether to proceed.

Comment: if `Cancel` is pressed it returns `None` . I think this line says it no? `print(USER_INP)`

Comment: Here you see a minimal reproducible example, if it is possible I would like a way that does not involve `if USER_INP == None`

Comment: It is that simple to use `if` in your case and I wonder why you don't want to use it.

Comment: Because I have this peice of code in my main program:

`if USER_INP.isspace() or not USER_INP:
        messagebox.showerror("ERROR", "Nothing was inserted. Try again")`

Comment: If there is no other way than I will probably start over and find another way

Answer (score 0):

```
if USER_INP is None:
    return
```

I just used this